# Use the limit definition to find the derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have no clue how to us the limit definition to find the derivative of the following function:

f(x)=x^2-1

Comment: Just apply the definition which is ??? By the way, welcome to this site !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am not sure what they mean by definition. I have been to loads of site to figure out the methodology of doing that and I am completely lost on this.

Comment: Consider the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h$ when $h\to 0$. Juts apply.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the definition:
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

substituting 
$$
f(x+h)=(x+h)^2-1=x^2+2hx+h^2-1
$$

can you do from this?

Comment: This is what I have done so far:
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{[(x+h)^2-1]-[(x^2-1)]}{h}
$$